# Electron app crashes while calling autoUpdater.checkForUpdates

Tags: electron

> electron : 6.0.9
>
> electron-updater: 4.1.2

Electron app being crashed when I'm calling `autoUpdater.checkForUpdates` 
without internet connection

App being crashed even surrounded in try catch block

```
    try {
        autoUpdater.checkForUpdates();
    } catch(e) {
        logEverywhere('Error, Failed to check for updates!');
    }
```

> Run this test on electron fiddle (with autoUpdater.setFeedURL("https://example.com/"))

```
Error: Error: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

(node:10144) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

(node:10144) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

(node:10144) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)

(node:10144) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)

(node:10144) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

(node:10144) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

Electron exited with code 0.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`autoUpdater.checkForUpdates()` is an asynchronous function that returns a promise. You can't catch these errors using a `try catch`.

This is how you catch errors:

```
autoUpdater.checkForUpdates().catch(err => {
    console.error(`Something went wrong`, err);
});
```

Comment: he could handle it with try/catch, if he uses async/await though. So your answer is only partially right.

Comment: I don't know what is happening here. but your answer is worked for me. I will accept this answer after testing

Comment: @FreddyDaniel if you don't know [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) (alternative to callbacks) yet, I recommend to understand and get used to them, as they are widely used. [Async](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) functions are a great help too, as they make promise chains easier. :)

Comment: @Rhayene is right. You should get to know Promises and how [Asynchronous JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous) works better. Async functions use implicit Promises so you should really understand how promises work before getting into them. They allow you to clean up your code and make it look like regular synchronous syntax.